# iframe navigation via textbox

Tags: html, iframe

I want to have a textbox in my HTML page, and also an `iframe`. When the user types in a URL in the textbox and clicks Submit, the `iframe` navigates to that page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple using jquery single line code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
function navigate() {
$('#iframe1').attr('src', $('#ifrmsite').val());
return false;
}
</script></head>
<body>
Enter website url below:<br/>
    <form onSubmit="return navigate();" method="get" action="">
        <input type="text" value="http://www.w3schools.com/" name="ifrmSite" id="ifrmsite"/> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<br /><br />
    <iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe1" src="" width="600" height="700" scrolling="auto">
    </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do we need `return false;` in `navigate()`?

Comment: For a form tag like <form action="test.asp"> the page will be redirect to test.asp when user press submit. Here we do not want to jump to other page so we return false in navigate() function. So form will not jump to page(action).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jquery:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function submitStuff(){
    document.getElementById('iFrame').src = 'http://' + document.theForm.url.value;
    return false ;
}
</script>
<form name="theForm" method="post" onsubmit="return submitStuff();">
<input name="url" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit">
</form>
<iframe id="iFrame" src="http://www.default.com"></iframe>
```